# Cooking brined green peppercorns to be soft

Tags: sauce, pepper

In my green pepper sauce I use brined green peppercorns. The supermarket has changed brands and the new one has seemingly fresh picked/uncooked corns in a brine.

I start my sauce by simmering dark beer and immediately add the peppercorns. With the new brand of peppercorns, as it simmered, the peppercorns were still hard/fresh after many tastings and adding water for the longer simmering time. The simmer time was about an hour.

Is there a better way to cook the peppercorns?

After the peppercorns are soft I add the rest of the recipe.